# Custom post type sort by date and time - Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, decibel

I'm using Decibel on Wordpress to enter concert dates and times for a music festival. There are 5-7 concerts every day.

I want to sort the concerts with date and time, from earliest in the day to latest?

Right now, I can't figure out how the list is organized -- not alphabetically, not by publish date. I'm using no code other than the basic [wolf_tour_dates].

Thanks for the help,
A.